# Have to run modprobe every time I want to use my webcam on MacBook Air

Tags: 14.04, kernel, webcam, macbook

Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBook Air.

Using the following method to install webcam on MacBook air:

```
cd /etc/local/src
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie/firmware
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo make
sudo install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

Install works but it's not permanent. I have to repeat the last three commands each time I want to use the webcam. Can anyone please tell me why and how to remedy this? I must be able to add a line in a file somewhere or...?

Comment: According to the README, you can blacklist the  `bdc_pci` module. That makes sense since `modprobe -r` removes it. To blacklist it, create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bdc_pci.conf` and add the text `blacklist bdc_pci` to the file. This *may* be sufficient. If not, the module is not getting loaded, so you may also need to add a line to the end of the file `/etc/modules` with just `facetimehd` (after these, obviously you need to reboot for anything to happen). If both of these together do not work, then there is something else needing to be done that is done by `depmod`...

Comment: Thank You Lots Zanna! -I added the line to "blacklist.conf" & the line to "module" and it has fixed the issue.

Comment: Fantastic! Would you like to write an answer below explaining what you did to help future visitors? Otherwise, I can write an answer myself.

Comment: I will try but it may need editing also the comment above was an error...1:sudo su 2:sudo chmod -rw /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bdc_pci.conf 3:sudo chmod -rw /etc/modules 4: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bdc_pci.conf 5:added a comment (using # first) detailing the blacklisting of this module, then added "blacklist bdc_pci" on the next line down (no quotation marks) 6:saved & exited. Then 7:sudo nano /etc/modules 8:put a comment (again using #) detailing why I was adding the module +on the next line down added the line "facetimehd" 9:saved & exited 10:sudo reboot

Comment: Note:1. I'm using cronopete to do daily backups so I didn't worry about backing up those two files prior to editing them but it would be a good idea to do so before carrying out the steps above . 2. I used nano but one could use their favourite text editor. 3. There was a "half a comment" above the outlined steps but I have worked out how to delete it.

Comment: I decided to write an answer to explain properly and because I was concerned by your use of `chmod` - you should never use `chmod` to edit root owned files. Also, comments are not for answers - as you can see it's hard to write anything readable in them, and they are meant for discussing how to improve posts etc, but it's my fault for putting my original suggestion in a comment rather than an answer - I was just not sure it would work. My bad, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You've compiled a kernel module `facetimehd` but it apparently conflicts with a module included in the Ubuntu kernel, `bdc_pci`. This command removes that driver from the kernel:

```
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
```

According to the [repository's wiki](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki) we can blacklist that module to overcome possible issues.

To do this, create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` with the suffix `.conf`. You can also simply add a line to the main blacklist `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, but making an individual file for each module you want to blacklist makes it easier to manage them. Global updates may replace the master blacklist with a new version from time to time, and you will have to edit it again.

To create and edit the file you'll need root permission. Do not use `chmod` or `chown`, just use `sudo`. For example, use:

```
sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bdc_pci.conf
```

This calls the default editor, usually `nano`, but you can use `sudo nano` `sudo vim` etc according to your preference. If you're calling a graphical text editor like gedit, use the `-H` flag to get a clean environment: `sudo -H gedit /etc...`

Add one line to the file

```
blacklist bdc_pci
```

Or if you want, add two lines, one a comment (starts with `#` so the line will be ignored) so future you and other folks will know the reason for blacklisting, for example

```
# conflicts with facetimehd webcam driver
blacklist bdc_pci
```

Save and exit, all done.

This might be sufficient, but if the new module is still not getting loaded automatically, the easiest way to made that happen is to make `systemd` load it by adding it to the file `/etc/modules`. You can also create a file in the directory `/etc/modules-load.d` with the extension `.conf`, and as with the blacklist, that would be marginally better practice.

```
sudoedit /etc/modules-load.d/facetimehd.conf
```

(or `sudoedit /etc/modules`, or call your favourite text editor as above...)

Add one line:

```
facetimehd
```

Or two:

```
# webcam driver, doesn't load itself 
facetimehd
```

Save and exit, and the module should be loaded at the next boot.

Comment: thanks for the tip about creating the additional "facetime.conf" file in /etc/modules-load.d. I ran an update today and had to do exactly that.

Comment: @BB88 nice :) I notice you mentioned putting a `#comment` before the blacklist which is also a great idea. I will add that to my answer in case it helps any future visitors